# Building a regex with packrat parsers in Scala

Tags: regex, parsing, scala

I have two packrat parsers in scala:

```
val symbols : PackratParser[String] =
    "{" | "}" | ">"

val keywords : PackratParser[String] =
    "BOOL" | "INT"
```

I want to build a parser that can recognise if a statement is composed of one or more of those two parsers. The way I'd usually do it is:

```
val statement : PackratParser[String] =
    regex( "[symbols | keywords]+".r )
```

But that wouldn't work because they're thinking I want the actual "symbols" or "keywords" token... Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use a regex this way. However, the whole point of parser combinators is that they can be combined!

```
val statement : PackratParser[List[String]] =
    rep1(symbols | keywords)
```

Comment: ah ok... but how do I make it so that there can be one or more of those two things? I've looked around and couldn't find any website that explains this

Comment: Documentation for `rep1` says: "A parser generator for non-empty repetitions.

rep1(p) repeatedly uses p to parse the input until p fails -- p must succeed at least once (the result is a List of the consecutive results of p) " Is that what you want? If not, please give some examples and expected results.

Comment: Yes, that's what I wanted! Thank you so much! I did not see that at all (even in the white Scala book!) Thanks!

Comment: Just look at http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/util/parsing/combinator/Parsers.html for other available combinators...

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov I have a problem with creating  a parser for my Regex would you please help me on that?  http://stackoverflow.com/q/30872527/3827280